# why apache web server running on windows 7 not able to allow external incoming connections

Tags: php, flash, apache, adobe, windows-7-x64

I have apache web server 2.4 set up on an Windows 7 - 64 bit in school with php 5.3 and mysql installed. This web server has a static ip address and I have allowed the Apache httpd.exe program on Windows 7 firewall.

When I tried to access the page in school (on the same LAN), I was able to access the page. But, when I tried to access it from home (with an external ip address) I wasn't able to access the web page hosted on the web server. When I tried to ping the static ip address of the web server in school it works but when I ping from outside school network, I get lost packets.

Further, I have Adobe Flash Media Server 4.5 installed on the same machine listening on ports 1935 and 1234.

I have also tried to uninstall and re-install apache but to no avail.

Any idea on how what is the problem here? Or any ways to test out the problem?

Is the problem because of Windows 7 tight firewall security? or 64-bit machine? or the adobe flash media server running on the same machine? or any misconfigurations out there in Apache?

Note: the static ip address is accessible and the server can serve a page when the server is running on windows xp previously. Recently, I just changed to windows 7 but the apache server can't seem to serve the same page.

Would really appreciate some help here!!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your server machine may have a firewall which allows connections, but the machine may stand behind the router which does not forward ports correctly. Have you checked this?

Comment: Yes, previously the static ip address is accessible and the server can serve a page when the server is running on windows xp. Recently, I just changed to windows 7 but the apache server can't seem to serve the same page.

Comment: This is a very important comment, it should be added to your original question. If it worked on XP and does not work on win7, there's still a chance that the router is misconfigured (I don't know, win7 system getting another IP than previous XP system?), but I'd look for the source of the problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The LAN is being protected by the router to the external network. You need to get the administrator to configure this router.